# filter for specific name, if not present skip to next line of code

Tags: excel, skip

I wrote this code last week to filter a column by an individual's name Copy active cells and paste them in a new work sheet saved as the individuals name. This was great until that individuals name was no longer in the data set. Is there a way to have a list of names and if those names do not exist move on to the next? The bulk of this macro was recorded.

```
 ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 3
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$U$188").AutoFilter Field:=13, Criteria1:= _
    "Sauber Justin"
Range("M32").Select
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 8
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 14
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
Range("U1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks.Add
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("M2").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Sauber Justin"
With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=10).Font
    .Name = "Arial"
    .FontStyle = "Regular"
    .Size = 11
    .Strikethrough = False
    .Superscript = False
    .Subscript = False
    .OutlineFont = False
    .Shadow = False
    .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
End With
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\e450040\Desktop\Sauber Justin.xlsm", _
    FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
Windows("ECROListExport.xlsm").Activate
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say where the list of names will be coming from. Regardless of the source, though, you're most likely going to want to look into loops and arrays. Below is some code to get you started. I've just left a comment where the actual copying and pasting should happen, since it seems you've already got that part down.

```
Sub Namer()

Dim NameArray(2) As String
NameArray(0) = "Sauber, Justin"
NameArray(1) = "Smith, George"
NameArray(2) = "Elwood, Marcus"

For i = 0 To UBound(NameArray)

'Check for Name
Dim HasName As Boolean
Dim TheCell As Range
For Each TheCell In Range("$A$1:$A$100")
If TheCell.Value = NameArray(i) Then
    HasName = True
End If
Next TheCell

'Filter and Copy
If HasName = True Then
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$100").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=NameArray(i)
'The copying and pasting code
End If

HasName = False

Next i

End Sub
```

Also, as a note, after you record a macro, you can pretty much always delete anything with ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn. That will make your code more readable for others.